# Prove that the columns of the similarity matrix of a diagonalization are the eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

I'm interested in [eigendecomposition of a matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix).

It is clear for me, that you can eigendecompose a matrix if and only if it is [diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix).

I'm looking for a short proof for that statement, that the columns of the [similarity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) of a diagonalization are the eigenvectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the $2 \times 2$ case you can generalize:

Suppose $M$ is an arbitrary $2 \times 2$ matrix with two eigenvalues, $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, and hence two corresponding eigenvectors, $v_1$ and $v_2$. Define a matrix $V$ whose columns are those two eigenvectors,

\begin{equation} V =\left( \begin{matrix} v_1 & v_2 \\ | & | \end{matrix} \right) \end{equation}
where those vertical bars indicate the column.

Then the action of $M$ on $V$ is the same as the action of $M$ on the individual columns. As those columns are also eigenvectors we may write

\begin{equation} MV =\left( \begin{matrix} Mv_1 & Mv_2 \\ | & | \end{matrix} \right) = \left( \begin{matrix} \lambda_1v_1 & \lambda_2v_2 \\ | & | \end{matrix} \right) =  \underbrace{\left( \begin{matrix} v_1 & v_2 \\ | & | \end{matrix} \right)}_{V} \underbrace{\left( \begin{matrix} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{matrix} \right)}_{D} \end{equation}

where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues. That is, $MV = VD$. Or

\begin{equation} M = VDV^{-1} \end{equation}